# Coinkite, Node.js authorization is failing, not sure why

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api

When I tried the code below with an api ket off http://forecast.io/ it worked. But when I tried it via https://coinkite.com/ I get a 401 unauthorized exception.

I don't understand why it is not going through. I have a separate project file which runs similar coinkite code, but is a command line application, and it gives me the right response.

This is the main point of execution,

```
/*global require*/
/*global console*/
/*global process*/
/*jslint nomen: true*/
/*global __dirname*/
/*jslint nomen: false*/

// Dependancies
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var currentPort = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', currentPort);

   // Here you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory
   /*jslint nomen: true*/
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
   /*jslint nomen: false*/
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   // Routes
   var coinkite = require('./routes/coinkite');

   app.use('/coinkite', coinkite);

   // Start Server
   app.listen(currentPort);
   console.log('Server is running at port: ' + currentPort);
```

This is the route for coinkite,

```
/*global require*/
/*global console*/
/*global module*/
/*global process*/
/*global CK_API */

// Dependancies

var express = require('express');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');

var CK_API_KEY = 'XX-XX-XXXX';
var CK_API_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
var CK_ENDPOINT = '/v1/my/self';
var CK_DATA = '';

var router_CK = express.Router();

router_CK.get('/', function (req, res) {
    'use strict';

    var ts = (new Date()).toISOString(),
        sign = CK_ENDPOINT + '|' + ts,
        hm = crypto.createHmac('sha256', CK_API_KEY).update(sign).digest('hex'),
    options = { uri: 'https://api.coinkite.com' + CK_ENDPOINT, headers: { 'X-CK-Key': CK_API_KEY, 'X-CK-Sign': hm, 'X-CK-Timestamp': ts }, json: true};

    request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body);
            CK_DATA = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(CK_DATA);
        }
    });

    res.render('coinkite-index', {data: CK_DATA});
});

// Return Router
module.exports = router_CK;
```

On a side note, if I wanted to pass a variable between modules in Node.js how would I do it?

Appreciate the help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very similar to the official JS code [from Coinkite github](https://github.com/coinkite/coinkite-javascript/blob/master/coinkite-api.js).

What error message did you get with the 401 response? That's usually very detailed and helpful.

---

#### Later

Looked again at your code, and I see the problem now... You have:

```
    hm = crypto.createHmac('sha256', CK_API_KEY).update(sign).digest('hex'),
```

But on that line, it should be CK_API_SECRET (not KEY) that is used in the HMAC.

Comment: It is a lot similar, am just playing with a couple of different node.js modules to get the job done. It just says "Service Unavailable"

Answer (score 0):

The code works, have to pass the CK_API_SECRET and not the CK_API_KEY for the sign.

```
hm = crypto.createHmac('sha256', CK_API_KEY).update(sign).digest('hex'),
```